# Why is this question on-hold for being "opinion based?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I would like to discuss about this question and as a result for every other similar that may be asked in this SE.

[Learning Curve of GameMaker and its limits](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105293/learning-curve-of-gamemaker-and-its-limits)

I copy paste here my comment after Mod Byte56 suggested.

*The learning curve is a concept that measures how an average person can learn something or achieve a task based on the creator of the term Hermann Ebbinghaus. Focus on the word "average". This means that a learning curve is not an opinion-based concept. As for the limits, I think it's not the case here. Define if you can create a multiplayer game in GameMaker or not for example, is not an opinion-based answer as well. Please reconsider to open the question or point me another place to discuss it thoroughly. Thank you*

Can you please share your thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I think the technical definition of "learning curve" is irrelevant to the issue at hand; regardless of what it means, this site isn't in the business of attempting to determine how quickly an individual *or* a hypothetical "average person" can learn something, or how difficult it would be for that person.

It's too soft a question, and consequently a poor fit for the site's format. It might not be "opinion-based" per se, but that is probably the closest applicable *default* close reason.

As for the aspect of the question that deals with the "limitations" of a game producted by GameMaker (or any other tool): that is simply too broad, as it is effectively an enumeration of the things a piece of software can or cannot do under particular circumstances (which are not clearly detailed in this particular case anyway).

No aspect of this question is appropriate for the StackExchange format; at least not as we adopt it on this particular StackExchange site. I think you would get far more useful responses if you ask this question on a more discussion-oriented forum, such as [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: Then the appropriate close reason should be off-topic or too-broad...